# How to hidden some values in my x-axe of my plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

my plot works fine but i have too many values and it is very hard to read clearly.

How can i modify my axe to display less value? I want to plot all values in `listoflists`, but not to display each date to each associated points from `nAnimals`(just the first , the second and the end date)

I searched here :

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axis

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


# listoflists=[[time1,numberOfAnimals],[time2,numberOfAnimals],...,
[timeN,numberOfAnimals]]

listoflists= [['120819154057347', 184],
 ['120819154057347', 184],
 ['120819154057348', 189],
 ['120819154057348', 189],
 ['120819154057379', 185],
 ['120819154057379', 185],
 ['120819154057431', 184],
 ['120819154057431', 184],
 ['120819154057445', 185],
 ['120819154057445', 185],
 ['120819154057493', 184],
 ['120819154057493', 184],
 ['120819154057574', 184],
 ['120819154057574', 184],
 ['120819154057598', 189],
 ['120819154057598', 189],
 ['120819154057615', 189],
 ['120819154057615', 189],
 ['120819154057623', 184],
 ['120819154057623', 184],
 ['120819154057646', 193],
 ['120819154057646', 193],
 ['120819154057663', 193],
 ['120819154057663', 193],
 ['120819154057696', 184],
 ['120819154057696', 184],
 ['120819154057769', 184],
 ['120819154057769', 184],
 ['120819154057782', 189],
 ['120819154057782', 189],
 ['120819154057801', 184],
 ['120819154057801', 184],
 ['120819154057802', 189],
 ['120819154057802', 189],
 ['120819154057831', 185],
 ['120819154057832', 185],
 ['120819154057884', 184],
 ['120819154057884', 184],
 ['120819154057897', 185],
 ['120819154057898', 185],
 ['120819154057946', 184],
 ['120819154057947', 184],
 ['120819154057989', 168],
 ['120819154057989', 168],
 ['120819154058000', 114],
 ['120819154058000', 114],
 ['120819154058010', 162],
 ['120819154058010', 162],
 ['120819154058011', 184],
 ['120819154058011', 184],
 ['120819154058035', 184],
 ['120819154058035', 184],
 ['120819154058045', 67],
 ['120819154058046', 67]]

# Extract information from listoflists
time=zip(*listoflists)[0]
nAnimals=zip(*listoflists)[1]
N=len(time)    
x=np.arange(N)
y=nAnimals
plt.xscale('linear') 
plt.xticks(x,time,rotation=90)
plt.plot(x,y,'r.')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can choose your favorite [Matplotlib Ticker and Formatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#module-matplotlib.ticker).

Comment: How about `np.linspace` instead of `np.arange` such as: `x=np.linspace(0,N,10)` - this will give you `10` ticks between `0` and `N`?

Comment: @Schorsch Thanx / Very nice trick ! First i had an error, but we need to have `x=np.arange` just add another line `axe_x=np.linspace(0,N,10)` and change `plt.xticks(x,time,rotation=90)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a different `x` (with lower resolution) for the tick locations:

```
x_ticks=np.linspace(0,N,10)
```

And then use it like this:

```
plt.xticks(x_ticks,time,rotation=90)
```